# Run local database with Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

What I need to know if I use service to create PostgreSQL in Heroku, can I set up this database locally in development mode?

I couldn't find in their documentation on how to do this.

Comment: you mean you created a PostgreSQL database using Heroku Postgres add-on?. If so you have just created a remote database on Heroku server. You can connect to it from any system. Just pass the right credentials in your development application. Credentials can be found from your application add-on page. Which framework are you using?

Comment: heroku database connection strings change time to time so you should find a way to maintain that as well

Comment: @Avatar yes I mean exactly that. Is there a way to setup the database locally as well? Somehow mirror the schema?

I'm using NodeJS & Express